# NGINX fake js file to PHP gives 404 but loads content

Tags: nginx

I have the following NGINX config:

```
location / { 
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
} 
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 365d; #for caching purposes
}
```

All requests are sent to index.php and all files with one of those extension will get an expiry header of 365 days.

This works fine until I request something like this.

```
domain.com/file.js
```

And file.js is not a static file but the request is handled by index.php. It reads the input of the REQUEST_URI and provides the correct dynamic js.

This all works very well except one thing, every request where the extension is in this list:
`(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)` 
and handled by PHP instead of an actual file will throw a 404 not found response header but DOES load its actual contents. When I use an extension other than in that list and let index.php handle the input (e.g. sitemap.xml) it gives a 200 OK response header.

This is what the error log produces:

```
public_html/file.js" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I had a similar issue with Apache when doing stuff with Angular/Http and Angular/HttpClient - I was redirecting all not found requests, which generated a 404 but did send my json, but the JS stopped at the 404.  Had to change my redirect from "if not found" to "if the file or directory they are asking for doesn't exist send a redirect to /api.php but keep the original request_uri" which generates a 200 instead of a 404 or 301/302 redirect.  Unfortunately I don't know about nginx so I can't give you a real answer....

Answer (score 0):

In your case, nginx uses only one `location`. For x.js it always ignores `try_files`. Try nesting:

```
location / { 
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 

   location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
      expires 365d; #for caching purposes
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content of the `.js` file is generated by the PHP script, then it is the PHP script that also sets the `404` status code. nginx doesn't alter the status code sent by the PHP application.